# c which include contains function

Tags: c, include

I received a large code file, that I didn't write. There's a function being used in that code that I want to use myself in a separate code file. Is there a quick and simple way to find which of the (many) includes in the original code file makes this function available?

Comment: No quick solution (because of dependencies, functions called indirectly, etc...). Is the code a library or a program?

Comment: Not really elegant, but maybe the simplest way: Redeclare the function with an incompatible type and try to compile (usually compilers give the position of the original declaration).

Comment: @mafso: This will fail for variadic functions or for functions that simply does not care about its arguments.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski: Why? Change the return type of the function and it's incompatible.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski: I meant redeclaring it, not using it, so you write e.g. `double printf(void);` at file scope (with gcc, this doesn't seem to work with standard library functions, however).

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way is usually to `grep` for the function name (pro tip: use `grep -rw` to search recursively and for whole-word matches only).  That assumes you have some idea which directories the header file may be in.

If that won't work, you can preprocess the file.  With GCC that's the `-E` option instead of `-c`.  This will output what the actual compiler sees, after #includes are resolved.  Then you can easily search in the preprocessed file for the function declaration and look above that for which file it came from.

Answer (score 2):

This completely depends on your developmnet environment. I often use [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/) tool (consider it as "better grep" for programmers) for that purpose, beside that I know that some IDEs have "go to definition" or "go to declaration" feature, so you can directly look for function's definition or its prototype.